# VIDEO_TOO_LONG_TITLE alert shown by UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, alert

I use a `UIImagePickerController` to take movies. The length of a movie is limited by setting the `videoMaximumDuration` property of the controller.
When one tries to take a longer movie, an alert is shown, as expected.

However **an unexpected additional alert** entitled *VIDEO_TOO_LONG_TITLE* is shown directly above the controls (see image below).
Apparently this is an iOS bug (only partly localized, no clip has been selected).

Is it possible to hide this unnecessary and inappropriate alert?

[image]

Comment: I filed a radar for this, dupe if you like: 29317021

Comment: Any news on how to resolve this and still let "allowsEditing" enabled?

Comment: In iOS 10.3.1 it is unfortunately still  the same.

Comment: Any update on it ? in i am still facing it in iOS 12.4. how can i view radar's current status?

Comment: in iOS 14, its still the same. There's no documentation on this as well. I want to set a proper text for this but I couldn’t find any way. I tried setting it in Localizable.strings and The user info but both did not work.

Comment: Too bad. I stopped writing bug reports, which takes time, but nearly all of my bug reports have never been answered nor processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
```

Comment: You are right, if `allowsEditing` is set to `false`, this alert is not shown. Unfortunately, I must allow editing. Anyway, I accept your answer, since there are surely cases where it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is quite old, but here's a solution to the problem that is still not addressed by Apple.

```
@implementation NSBundle (UIImagePickerControllerLocalizationFix)

+ (void) load {
    SEL const selector = @selector (localizedStringForKey:value:table:);
    Method const localizedStringMethod = class_getInstanceMethod (self, selector);
    NSString *(*originalImp) (NSBundle *, SEL, NSString *, NSString *, NSString *) = (typeof (originalImp)) method_getImplementation (localizedStringMethod);
    IMP const updatedImp = (typeof (updatedImp)) imp_implementationWithBlock (^(NSBundle *bundle, NSString *key, NSString *value, NSString *tableName) {
        NSString *const result = originalImp (bundle, selector, key, value, tableName);
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"VIDEO_TOO_LONG_TITLE"] && [result isEqualToString:key]) {
            static NSBundle *properLocalizationBundle = nil;
            static NSString *properLocalizationTable = nil;
            static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
            dispatch_once (&onceToken, ^{
                NSString *const originalBundleName = bundle.infoDictionary [(NSString *) kCFBundleNameKey];
                NSArray <NSBundle *> *const frameworkBundles = [NSBundle allFrameworks];
                for (NSBundle *frameworkBundle in frameworkBundles) {
                    NSString *const possibleTableName = [originalBundleName isEqualToString:tableName] ? frameworkBundle.infoDictionary [(NSString *) kCFBundleNameKey] : tableName;
                    NSString *const localizedKey = originalImp (frameworkBundle, selector, key, value, possibleTableName);
                    if (![localizedKey isEqualToString:key]) {
                        properLocalizationBundle = frameworkBundle;
                        properLocalizationTable = possibleTableName;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!(properLocalizationBundle && properLocalizationTable)) { // Giving up
                    properLocalizationBundle = bundle;
                    properLocalizationTable = tableName;
                }
            });

            return originalImp (properLocalizationBundle, selector, key, value, properLocalizationTable);
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    });
    method_setImplementation (localizedStringMethod, updatedImp);
}

@end
```